# piechart and colpex xml

Tags: xml, apache-flex, charts

If I had an XML data like this:

```
<data>
<recored id='1'>
<node1>something</node1>
<node2>
<num>5</num>
<per>55%</per>
</node2>
</recored>
</data>
```

and I want to use a pie chart where my dataprovider is set to the sub node "per" in "node 2" !
how can I go back up and set the nameField to "node1" ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#parent%28%29 and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/series/PieSeries.html#labelFunction

If you are using something like `testXML.record.node2` as dataProvider and "num" as series "field"  you can implement a `labelFunction` like this

```
public function node1LabelFunction(data:Object, field:String, index:Number, percentValue:Number):String
{
      return data.parent().node1.text()
}

<mx:PieSeries 
      dataProvider="{testXML.record.node2}" 
      field="num" 
      labelFunction="node1LabelFunction" 
      labelPosition="callout" 
      />
```